# setup.py install within conda env via Docker

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

So I'n new-ish to Docker.

What I'm trying to do:

- create a docker image (that puts you into an anaconda enviroment and downloads some libraries via conda), within that enviroment run a setup.py install so that the library CPLEX is also in the image
- Build the image. Next I run the image, and set a scratch directory that should have all the python programs in it that I want to run.

This is my docker file:

```
## syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
from continuumio/miniconda3



RUN conda create --name opt python=3.7
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/mro_env/bin:$PATH
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate opt"
RUN conda install -c conda-forge fenics
RUN conda install -c conda-forge scipy
RUN conda install -c conda-forge numpy
RUN conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
RUN conda install -c conda-forge ipopt
RUN conda install -c conda-forge glpk
RUN conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
RUN conda install -c conda-forge pandas
RUN conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn




ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

COPY CPLEX_Studio129/ /CPLEX_Studio129/

COPY . /codes/

RUN cd /CPLEX_Studio129/ && python cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_osx/setup.py install
WORKDIR /codes/
RUN cd /codes/
```

Next I build the image, and then run the image :

```
sudo docker build -t ex:latest .
docker run --rm -it  --entrypoint /bin/bash  ex

    (base) root@bc9beca93d69:/codes# python test_cplex.py 
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/codes/test_cplex.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cplex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cplex'
(base) root@bc9beca93d69:/codes# ls
```

For what its worth, if I make /CPLEX_Studio129/  the WORKDIR, and install the library, then start a python in that directory, and try to import cplex it works. But my hope was that it would work when I run a program that imports CPLEX in /codes/, which it cannot find.

Any tips, and a bried explation of where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the traceback is cut off. Could you check and put the full one for us? There are some things in the docker file that strike me as strange: 1) `ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/mro_env/bin:$PATH` - why do you need to put the path to some environment here? 2) `RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate opt"` this should have no effect as the RUN statements are isolated from each other AFAIK.

Comment: Hey Cel, I updated the error output. You are right that I missed a little bit of it. With those commands I was trying to be put in the anaconda local enviroment I created called "opt".

Comment: Hey Cel, I updated the error output. You are right that I missed a little bit of it. With those commands I was trying to  activate the anaconda local enviroment I created called "opt", and download some libraries. Afterwards, while in this local enviroment, I was going to install CPLEX via the setup.py install. Afterwards (while being in this enviroment), I was going to cd to the codes directory which has my codes, and my hope was that I would have all the neccessary librares so that I could run my code.